# Подсчет периода в запросе

Tags: mysql

Привет всем, я не очень шарю в запросах. Надо сделать запрос, который считает стаж, который проработал рабочий.

т.е. К примеру он устроился на работу 01-10-2000 и уволился 01-10-2012.Надо чтобы он каким-то образом рассчитал, что рабочий проработал 12 лет,  10 месяц и 1 день.Вожможно ли вообще такое?

Comment: @Adelante, Это вопрос на форум [ХэшКод](http://hashcode.ru/). Только заголовок надо сменить, он не соответствует действительности.

Answer (score 1):

```
select name, lastviz_date, CURRENT_DATE(), DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), lastviz_date) as daysfrom doctor
```

вот примерчик, получаем в днях

```
name    lastviz_date    CURRENT_DATE()  days
```

---

```
Тест1       24.06.2012Василий     11.11.2011  24.06.2012  **226**Андрей      05.01.2012  24.06.2012  **171**Роман       10.11.2011  24.06.2012  **227**Василий                 24.06.2012  Иван        05.01.2012  24.06.2012  **171**Дмитрий     05.01.2012  24.06.2012  **171**Виктория    05.01.2012  24.06.2012  **171**
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, то что ты мне подсказал я сделал. Но мне не такой "формат" нужен.к примеру на работу  приняли 12 мая 2001 ---- а уволили 24 ноября 2008 === так вот мне надо что бы он не суму дней лет и месяцев выбивал, а просто показал что тот рабочий проработал лет: 7|месяцев: 6|дней: 13

Answer (score 0):

> над сделать запросик который считает стаж который рабочий проработал. т.е.

Судя по тексту Вы не знаете как сделать "запросик" в отдел кадров, ну дык возьмите цветы и шампанское, Вам все на счетах по считают. Или перечитайте свой вопрос и определитесь с какой базой Вы работаете. В любом случае "запросик" сделает выборку, а вот "скриптик" с этой выборкой сделает то чего Вы захотите.

Comment: слушай я через NaviCat c sql базой работаюнаписал вот такое "   select `locdemunca`.`kid` AS `kid`,`locdemunca`.`kid_prof` AS `kid_prof`,`locdemunca`.`compania` AS `compania`,`locdemunca`.`functia` AS `functia`,`locdemunca`.`dataocupare` AS `dataocupare`,`locdemunca`.`dataeliberare` AS `dataeliberare`,`locdemunca`.`pedagogic` AS `pedagogic` from `locdemunca` where (isnull(`locdemunca`.`dataeliberare`) and (`locdemunca`.`pedagogic` = 'Pedagogic'))   "но он как бы суму считает я просто не правильно делаю уверен на 101%но если есть ссылка на литературу или на похож тему, подскажи плиз

Comment: сравнение 2-х дат для mysql - DATEDIFF(), получаем результат в днях. Смотрите здесь http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html